# Derivatives of matrix functions - chain rule

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I have some problems with calculating the derivative of complex matrix functions which involves the chain rule.

1.) I found the following matrix derivative in multiple papers:
$$ d\mathbf{X} \log\det\left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H\right) = \text{tr}\left( \mathbf{B}^H \left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H \right)^{-1} \mathbf{B} d \mathbf{X}\right)$$

They obviously used the following rule:
$$d \mathbf{X} \log\det(\mathbf{X}) = \text{tr}(\mathbf{X}^{-1}d\mathbf{X})$$
[see e.g. The Matrix Cookbook eq. 43, p.8]
and additionally they must have used the chain rule. But I don't understand why it is:
$$ \mathbf{B}^H \left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H \right)^{-1} \mathbf{B} $$
and not (exchange of the conjugate transpose $(\cdot)^H$outside of $(\cdot)^{-1}$):
$$ \mathbf{B} \left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H \right)^{-1} \mathbf{B}^H $$

because
$$ d\mathbf{X} (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H) = \mathbf{B}d\mathbf{XB}^H$$
Can someone explain this result to me?

2.) My overall goal is to compute a derivative of the following form:
$$ d\mathbf{X} \log\det\left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{BXB}^H + \mathbf{CXC}^H\right) $$
Therefore I would like to understand how to compute this derivatives.

Thank you in advance,
Enzo.

Reference:
https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: To understand complex matrix derivatives, see the Hjørungnes' book **Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives: With Applications in Signal Processing and Communications**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $f$ the function 
$$ f(X) = \def\I{\mathord{\rm Id}}\I + BXB^*. $$
We have, as you write correctly 
$$ f'(X)H = BHB^* $$
Hence, using 
$$ (\log \det)'(X)H = \def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}\tr(X^{-1}H) $$
we get, using the chain rule 
\begin{align*}
  (\log\mathord\det\circ f)'(X)H &= (\log \det)'\bigl(f(X)\bigr)f'(X)H\\
     &= \tr\bigl(f(X)^{-1}f'(X)H\bigr)\\
     &= \tr\bigl((\I + BXB^*)^{-1}BHB^*\bigr)\\
     &= \tr \bigl(B^*(\I + BXB^*)^{-1}BH\bigr)
\end{align*}
In the last equation we used the property $\tr(AB) = \tr(BA)$ of the trace. (I used $H$ where you used $\partial X$).

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. Coming back to my second question, adopting your notation I get: $$\left( I + BXB^* + CXC^* \right)'(X)H = tr(B^*(I+BXB+CXC)^{-1}BH) + tr(C^*(I+BXB+CXC)^{-1}CH)$$ Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @Enzo Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hi Martini, could you please help me with this question of mine? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991410/a-doubt-on-the-general-chain-rule-to-derive-scalar-functions-w-r-t-matrices