# A doubt on the general chain rule to derive scalar functions w.r.t. matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

From what I could understand reading some of the answers here, and reading some pdfs on matrix derivation, the general rule for scalar-to-matrix derivation is:

Let $g(X)=U$.

$$\frac{d}{d X}f(g(X))=\frac{d}{d X_{ij}}f(g(X)) = \sum_{k}\sum_l \frac{\partial}{\partial U_{kl}}f(U)\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}U_{kl}=Tr\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial U}f(U)\right)^\intercal \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ij}}U\right)$$

However, the differential notation is usually more used. And the differential formula I've seen being used is if
$$df=Tr\left(\left(A \right)^\intercal dX \right)$$ then $$\frac{d}{d X}f(g(X))=A$$

How does one reconcile both notations?

Comment: Couple things, why are you making things more complicated? You have a composition of functions rather than just a single function, which is completely unnecessary. Also what do you mean by a general rule for scalar to matrix derivation? This can't be the general rule if it only applies to composites of functions. Also what is $A$? And lastly, the fact that the objects are matrices is completely irrelevant to taking derivatives, its the same as taking the derivative of a vector to scalar function. Also I'm not quite sure which possible matrix is intended by $\frac{\partial}{\partial U}f(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you've simply written
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial U}:\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \cr
}$$
In the second case, you've stated the **definition** of the differential in terms of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= A:dX \cr
 &= \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\Big):dX \cr
 &= \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial U}:\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}\Big):dX \cr
}$$

I'm not sure what needs to be reconciled; the two cases are consistent with one another.

Note however that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}$ is a $4^{th}$ order tensor, which will be tricky to work with.

*[Instead of the functional notation ${\,\rm Tr}\big(A^T\,dX\big)\,$ I've used the product notation $\big(A:dX\big)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I was mixing $df(X)= \sum_{k}\sum_l \frac{\partial}{\partial X_{kl}}f(X)dX_{kl}= Tr((\frac{\partial}{\partial X}f(X))^\intercal dX)$, with the first case I stated.